# Siblings in French

Tags: traduction, vocabulaire, anglais, usage, anglicismes

In English there is *siblings*, in German *Geschwister*. To the best of my knowledge, French does not have a single word but rather uses *(les) frères et sœurs* construction.

So does French lack indeed a single word as I think, for such a basic situation? Can we use sibling(s) as it is in French?

Comment: So if I met two cousins how would I ask 'which of your parents are "siblings"?' <<Lesquels de vos parents sont frères ou sœurs ?>>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a word: *adelphe*. It is not really used anymore, but it has exactly the same meaning as *sibling* in English.

Comment: The existence of a word in a dictionary is not proof of use.

Comment: @Lambie "It is not really used anymore"...

Comment: So little used that most French speakers would need a dictionary nowadays to check what it means :-)

Comment: @Frank Love your siblings in Philadelphia!

Answer (score 8):

There is a term: "fratrie", but it lacks the non-gender feeling that siblings has. I think that's why it's not used as often as in other languages, because of this bias.

Still "fratrie" encompasses brothers and sisters in a family.

Comment: Merci.  Like fratelli in Italian language and fratria in Greek language.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Obviously same roots here :)

Comment: Important precision (that to me explains why it isn't used as often as in other languages more than the gender bias): "une fratrie" refers to **all** the brothers and sisters in a family, and can't be used to designate a single member, contrary to "a sibling".

Comment: @Blackhole: But even in English, if you're talking about a specific sibling, you're much more likely to say "my sister" than "my sibling".

Answer (score 6):

I’m a Francophone here and no we don’t have a word for "siblings" in French, actually not in Canada for sure.

By the way, I would never use "adelphe" ou "fratrie", because the word adelphe is not known in French even if it’s in the dictionary, we never use this word. For the word "fratrie", I don’t know about France, but in Canada people will probably be confused, because even me I had to search to found the real meaning of the word.

To make sure everyone understands, just say : frère et sœur, comme dans la phrase: As-tu des frères et sœurs?

NB : By the way, don’t forget that there are a lot more words in English than in French.

Comment: This is accurate. Everyone says: frères et soeurs unless they are anthropologists or genealogists.

Comment: « Fratrie » un un mot très courant en France.

Comment: @Lambie I don't understand why you are always so negative and absolute. To the best of my knowledge fratrie is not a word only used by anthropologists and genealogists.

Comment: On trouve _fratrie_ 1000 fois sur le seul site de LaPresse (Canada). C'est un site d'actualité grand public. Courant au Québec, je sais pas, mais faut pas charrier non plus. La quantité de mots au lexique anglais n'est pas pertinent, il s'agit surtout de choix lexicographiques et en français on a davantage de locutions pour dire des termes qu'on aurait par exemple en nom composé en anglais. En plus le lexique anglais est un ramassis de trucs qui ne sont plus en usage, et est très libéral. Le lexique courant est comparable en nombre de mots.

Comment: fratie n'est pas courant pour sibling. On dit en anglais: Do you have any siblings? + J'ai trois fraties? I don't think so. Avez-vous des frères et soeurs?

Answer (score 3):

Well,
If I refer myself to the French Academy Dictionary, the word "fratrie" would be more likely to be defined as the "group composed of your siblings" (siblings having there the emphasis put on the individuals obviously).
And adelphos/adelphé are greek words and subsequently don't have an entry in the dictionary, at the very least they weren't used in French around the publication of the 1st Edition of the Dictionary (1694) until now, meaning they were never used...

source (in French):
https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/DNP0109

Comment: Bienvenue sur French Language SE.  This reads like a comment other answers that mention fratrie and adelphe.  Please take a moment to [tour] the site and see the [help], and welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Sibling used to mean *relative*, brothers-and-sisters is a modern evolution of this ancient germanic word.

Geschwister has a feminine bias (Schwester).

Fratrie has a masculine bias (frère).

All these words, i*ncluded the French word contrary to your supposition*, are used to mean brothers-and-sisters, but not the Greek φρατρία the meaning of which being more tribe than family (another evolution of the Indo-european root).

Answer (score 2):

Single words have been found but are not countable (in context, for individual siblings), unlike *frères et soeurs*. This simple solution should prove insightful:

> — Vous êtes combien chez vous ? 
>  — Dans ma famille nous sommes
> quatre enfants, en plus de ma mère et de mon père.

A translation to *siblings* (or even a substantive in the question phrase) is not required for this basic situation.

Comment: p.s. _...en plus de mes parents_. Voir si la question justifie l'ajout.

Answer (score 0):

Complément des réponses : il existe quelques attestations du mot "sibling(s)" en francais ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sibling%2Csiblings&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csibling%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csiblings%3B%2Cc0)). Selon
https://fr.wiktionary.org c'est très [rare](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/sibling#Nom_commun). Le même lemme [dit](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=les%20germains%2Cles%20siblings%2Cles%20adelphes%2Cses%20germains%2Cses%20siblings%2Cses%20adelphes&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cles%20germains%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cles%20siblings%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cses%20germains%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cses%20siblings%3B%2Cc0) que *germain* est plus courant (pour l'anthropologie au moins).

Comment: Attention, c'est un terme technique d'anthropologie que >99% des Français ne comprendraient pas.

Comment: @Gilles C'est noté ; réponse modifiée. Merci !

Comment: Je ne pense pas que le mot lemme s'applique: Proposition dont la démonstration prépare souvent celle d'un théorème. Larousse.

Comment: Seule l'expression : « Ils sont *cousins germains* » est usitée qui comprend aussi « Ils sont ***tous** cousins germains* » pour inclure la gent féminine.

Comment: @Lambie **Lemme** TLFi *B. − LEXICOGR. Forme graphique choisie conventionnellement comme adresse dans un lexique.*

Comment: @Lambie I am neither a native speaker nor a linguist but I know the lemme has both the mathematical and lingustic meaning. The same holds true in English as well.

Comment: Ah, **forme graphique**.

Comment: @Dimitris Oubliez (un peu) la sororité ou la fraternité car il est temps de découvrir le concept inclusif qu’est l’adelphité. Un mot qui n’est pas nouveau en français mais qui s’est de plus en plus imposé dans les discours féministes. Ainsi, vous avez peut-être vu fleurir sur les réseaux sociaux, sur des pancartes en manif ou sur des collages féministes les termes « adelphes » et « adelphité ». On vous détaille ce que représente ce terme et dans quel contexte l’utiliser.

Comment: Lien: https://www.peaches.fr/lifestyle/healthy-life/quest-ce-que-le-concept-dadelphite-au-croisement-des-notions-de-sororite-et-fraternite-15511.html Et voila que le mot revient!!/// Adieu frères et sœurs, bonjour les adelphes ! Quand solidarité et communauté se croisent entre fraternité et sororité, elles donnent naissance à l'adelphité ! //Il faut mieux ne pas faire des commentaires personnels. Surtout quand on se trompe.

Answer (score -1):

Il est à noter que, comme souvent dans la langue française, le masculin l'emporte sur le féminin. Aussi on peut dire : "tes frères", même si dans le lot il y a des filles, pour désigner "tes frères et sœurs". "La fratrie" englobe elle aussi tout les enfants.

Comment: Merci pour votre réponse. Je ne suis pas locuteur français mais je sais que de nos jours pas tout le monde accepte ledit "masculin générique". (voir articles sur la féminisation de la langue française: https://www.nouvelobs.com/societe/20190228.OBS0960/feminisation-de-la-langue-l-academie-francaise-fait-enfin-sa-revolution.html ; https://www.grazia.fr/news-et-societe/news/pour-ou-contre-la-feminisation-de-la-langue-francaise-917468 etc.)

Comment: Aussi https://www.europe1.fr/societe/feminiser-la-langue-ce-nest-pas-la-tordre-cest-revenir-a-un-usage-naturel-et-ancien-3862355

Comment: Auriez-vous une référence quant au terme "frères" englobant aussi les soeurs ? Autant je comprends le terme "fratrie" dans ce sens, autant le terme frères désigne pour moi les membres masculins de la fratrie. Il me semble que dans le language courant, "frères et soeurs" est souvent employé quand-même pour lever toute ambiguïté

Comment: Quand j'etais petit dans ma famille, quand mon père me disait " va chercher tes frères" il sous-entendais tout mes frères et soeurs. Il est vrai cependant que ce genre d'utilisation dans le language courant est rare de nos jours.